# moment.js give wrong time in diffent timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Epoch time for 2nd July 2018 , 11 PM. (IST)

```
> moment('2018-07-02T23:00:00.000').unix()
1530552600
```

Now When I convert from epoch to IST, It added 7 minute Extra.

```
> moment.unix(1530552600).tz("Asia/Kolkata").format("DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM z");
'02:07:2018 23:07 IST'
```

When converted to ET timezone , It gives 30 minute less from IST timezone. ET is 9.5 behind IST so it should have been "02:07:2018 01:30:00 EDT'

```
> moment.unix(1530552600).tz("America/New_York").format("DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM z");
'02:07:2018 13:07 EDT'
```

[image: EDT]

IST

[image]

Comment: _“It added 7 minute Extra”_ - no it didn’t - you made it output the _month_ in that place, instead of actual _minutes_.

Answer (score 4):

your formatting string is wrong, you used `MM` (month) instead of `mm` (minutes)

try

```
moment.unix(1530552600).tz("Asia/Kolkata").format("DD:MM:YYYY HH:mm z");
```

for all other formats see the [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, didn't even notice this thing and wasted too much my time on this.  Thanks again.